# using inflater and deflater to compressmore than one time

Tags: android

I am using inflater and deflater to compress and uncompress bytes later 
I was compressing bytes and it was working so good, but I had problem that the bytes still have a little big size.
So I thought in compressing it twice times, but I am getting error 
date formation exception.

and this is my code to compress and uncompress:

```
    public static byte[] compress(byte[] data) {
    Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
    deflater.setInput(data);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
    deflater.finish();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (!deflater.finished()) {
        int count = deflater.deflate(buffer); // returns the generated code... index
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    try {
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();
    //LOG.debug("Original: " + data.length / 1024 + " Kb");
    //  LOG.debug("Compressed: " + output.length / 1024 + " Kb");
      System.out.println("original" + data.length/1024 +"kb");
    System.out.println("compressed" + output.length +"b");
    return output;
}
public static byte[] decompress(byte[] data) throws IOException {
    Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
    inflater.setInput(data);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (!inflater.finished()) {
        int count = 0;
        try {
            count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
        } catch (DataFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    outputStream.close();
    byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();
    System.out.println("original revived" + data.length/1024 +"kb");
    System.out.println("uncompressed" + output.length/1024 +"kb");
    return output;
}
```

and i compress like this:

```
byte data[] =  compress(byteArrayOutputStream1.toByteArray());
            byte data_2[] =compress(data);//////double compress
```

and I uncompress this way:

```
byte[] us =decompress(s);
byte[] us2 =decompress(us);
```

Comment: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: incorrect header check
                  at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateImpl(Native Method)
                  at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:237)
                  at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:214)